# c# - How to call/link a workflow on a web application from a c# program?

Tags: c#

I have a C# (WinForms) application that can scan documents via a printer. After scanning, I will be able to enter document details on it and have a button to finalize the documents. The documents details and info will be stored in my database ABC in certain tables.

Now, I have another web application written in Java(IntelliJ) that has some button functionality to upload documents and then start a workflow and route it to another user to approve the document. I won't go into detail on the specifics. This application also connects to the same database ABC.

So now comes the tougher part, I need to link these two applications in a way that when I finalize my document
on the C# application, it has to auto trigger the workflow on the web application side. Rather than manually starting the workflow on the web application, it would just call or trigger the workflow, so I do not need to access the web application at all for the process to start.

```
 private void FinButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            int count = 0;
            var txtBoxFields = new List<TextBox>
            {
                textBox1,
                textBox2,
                textBox3,
                textBox4,
                textBox5,
                textBox6,
                textBox7,
                textBox8,
                textBox9,
                textBox10,
                textBox11,
                textBox12,
                textBox13,
                textBox14,
                textBox15
            };

            var templateFields = new List<String>
            {
                "T1",
                "T2",
                "T3",
                "T4",
                "T5",
                "T6",
                "T7",
                "T8",
                "T9",
                "T10",
                "T11",
                "T12",
                "T13",
                "T14",
                "T15"
            };

            //long tid = 0;

            //Start insert query into templatebatch table in db
            var dbConnection2 = DBConnection.Instance();
            dbConnection2.DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbName"];
            if (dbConnection2.IsConnect())
            {
                bool test = true;

                for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
                {
                    var input = txtBoxFields[i - 1].Text;
                    var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO templateinfo(TID, THEADER, " + templateFields[i - 1] + ") VALUES(@tid, @theader,@t" + i + ")";
                    var insertCmd = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, dbConnection2.Connection);
                    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tid", tid);
                    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theader", "N");


                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                    {
                        count = 1;
                        insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t" + i, String.Empty);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (test)
                        {
                            insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t" + i, txtBoxFields[i - 1].Text);
                            insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            test = false;

                            var selectQuery = "select TINFOID from templateinfo where TID=" + tid + " and THEADER = 'N'";
                            var selectCmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, dbConnection2.Connection);
                            var selectReader = selectCmd.ExecuteReader();

                            using (MySqlDataReader dr = selectReader)
                            {
                                while (dr.Read())
                                {
                                    tinfoid = Convert.ToInt32(dr["TINFOID"]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var updateQuery = "update templateinfo set " + templateFields[i - 1] + "='" + txtBoxFields[i - 1].Text + "' where TINFOID = '" + tinfoid + "' and TID=" + tid + " and THEADER='N'";
                            var updateCmd = new MySqlCommand(updateQuery, dbConnection2.Connection);
                            var updateReader = updateCmd.ExecuteReader();
                            using (var reader = updateReader)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


            }


            if (count == 1)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Input field(s) cannot be left empty.");
            }

            //Finalize here
            var client = new LTATImagingServiceClient();
            client.Finalize(userID, tid, tinfoid, batchID);

            Debug.WriteLine(userID + ", " + tid + ", " + tinfoid + ", " + batchID);

            var batchName = templateView.SelectedNode.Text;

            var folderPath = @"C:\temp\batches\" + mastertemplatename + @"\" + subtemplatename + @"\" + batchName + @"\";


            ThumbnailLists.Items.Clear();
          //  var img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\temp\batch-done.png");

            if (ImageBox.Image != null)
            {
                ImageBox.Image.Dispose();
            }

            ImageBox.Image = null;

            try
            {
                using (new Impersonation(_remoteDomain, _remoteUser, _remotePassword))
                {
                  //  MessageBox.Show(_remoteUser);
                  //  MessageBox.Show(_remotePassword);
                    var tPath = @"\\126.32.3.178\PantonSys\SAM\Storage\3\" + mastertemplatename + @"\" + subtemplatename + @"\" + batchName + @"\";
                    bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(tPath);

                    if (!exists)
                    {
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(tPath);
                    }

                    string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*");
                    foreach (var file in fileList)
                    {
                        File.Copy(file, tPath + Path.GetFileName(file));
                    }

                    CurrentPageBox.Text = "";
                    NumberPageBox.Text = "";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            var dbConnection = DBConnection.Instance();
            dbConnection.DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbName"];

            if (dbConnection.IsConnect())
            {
                var deleteBatchQuery = "DELETE FROM templatebatch WHERE batchname ='" + templateView.SelectedNode.Text + "'";
                var deleteBatchCmd = new MySqlCommand(deleteBatchQuery, dbConnection.Connection);
                var deleteBatchReader = deleteBatchCmd.ExecuteReader();
                using (var reader = deleteBatchReader)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                    }
                }

                templateView.Nodes.Remove(templateView.SelectedNode);
                Directory.Delete(folderPath, true);
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Transferred.");

                foreach (var txtFields in txtBoxFields)
                {
                    txtFields.Text = "";
                    txtFields.Enabled = false;
                }

                finButton.Visible = false;
                finButton.Enabled = false;

            }

            bindButton.Visible = false;

        }
```

Would this be possible to achieve or just being far-fetched? 
I would appreciate any suggestions or pointers on this. Do let me know if there is anything unclear in my explanation.

EDIT:

```
Request URL: http://126.32.3.178:8111/process/taskmanager/start/start.jsp
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 126.32.3.178:8111
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Is there a way I could call this from the C# application?

Comment: your web app starts its job when you click some button or link on a web page?

Comment: Basically inside my web app, I click "Start workflow" button, then I can upload some documents and when finished, I click " Submit" button and then the workflow has begun. So I was wondering on my C# side, if I could automatically call the " Submit" button on the web app, then it shall actually trigger the workflow.

Comment: then you can look for what request is done when you submit your form (in developer console of your browser) and do the simular request in your C# app with [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: The request is called form is start.jsp . Do you want so see the code? I've been struggling this for many days, can't figure what is wrong

Comment: no, can you show us actual HTTP request, which is invoked, when you hit "Submit" button? You can found it in developer console of your browser.

Comment: Okay see my edited post

Comment: There should be also a form data that is sended in developer console. What paramters are sended?

Comment: What about instead of using HTTP client request, I can manually insert into tables in the db in C# that are involved in the transaction right after the submit button is invoked? That way, I am pumping in data to the tables the same way my web app is pumping into the same tables to trigger the workflow. Will that work?

Comment: Sure, you may rewrite your Java logic in C#, in this case you don't even need your Java web-app.

Comment: I think i need to have a look at it because it's about finding the right table to pump

Comment: damn it's harder than expected doing this way, do you think htpp request is easier?

Comment: I think that HTTP request is easier, cuz there you need to implement just one method instead of porting some logic from Java to C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can send your file directly from your C# app with use of [Http client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2). Here is code sample:

```
private async Task<bool> Upload(string filePath)
{
    const string actionUrl = @"http://126.32.3.178:8111/process/taskmanager/start/start.jsp";
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

    var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        formData.Add(fileContent, fileName);
        var response = await client.PostAsync(actionUrl, formData);
        return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
}
```

Also, note that there maybe some sort of authentication should be performed before you can post a request.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I think there is more to that to get this working. You could see my suggestion above

Comment: Just a question, why do you pass a file parameter in the statement?

Comment: form data is a like a key-value dictionary, so, your file need a key:) You need to replace it with value that your Java web-app expect. That's why I ask you about form data in question comments.

Comment: For this scenario, my web application must be running for this to call the url right?

Comment: sure, your web app is supposed to be running

Comment: Could the filepath also be specified to get the folder itself and it's file content inside?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Specified where?

Comment: I am not too sure if GetAllBytes exists in the current context. Also, paramFileBytes does not contain a declaration?

Comment: [File.ReadAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=netframework-4.7.2) is part of .net since version 2.0. `paramFileBytes` is a typo - fixed.

Comment: Oh I see. I meant when your solution only uploads file instead of folder, is that correct? It is possible if say I want to upload a folder " Folder1" that inside contains image 1, image 2, etc ? That;s what i meant

Comment: I am running version 4.0 , somehow there's isn't File.ReadAllBytes. I need to download the assemblies probably

Comment: try add `using System.IO;` or just call it directly: `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(...)`

Comment: I also would like to add it's probably not a good idea to add "private" inside an button event

Comment: Okay I know why, I need to use ReadAllBytes but somehow I kept using GetAllBytes as mentioned by your solution. Now I know.

Comment: oh, another typo. fixed

Comment: Okay everything seems fine now, except await client.PostAsync.....It says Task<HttpResponseMessage> does not contain definition for GetAwaiter and no accessible method GetAwaiter acception a first argument of type Task<HtppResponseMessage>

Comment: `async/await` is .net 4.5+. You need to upgrade you target framework, or install [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) nuget package, or refactor this code to .net 4.0.